# What is the cause for duplicated XML sitemap links?

Tags: 7

I have a site where I have [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) installed. I am using XML sitemap menu and XML sitemap custom, I see duplicate links in my sitemap.xml file, So what is the cause for that?